# Print out the value with the highest number of occurrences in a file

Tags: bash, awk

In a bash shell script, I want to go through a list of numbers and then print out the number that occurs most often. If there are several different numbers appearing an equal amount of times, I want to print the highest number. For example, in a file like this:

10
10
10
15
15
20
20
20
20

I want to print the value 20.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] or you will likely get an answer that reflects the minimal effort you put into asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are in a file, one per line:

`sort < myfile | uniq -c | sort -r | head -1`

without the count:

`A=$(sort < myfile | uniq -c | sort -r | head -1)
set $A
echo $2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command -

`echo 10 10 10 15 15 20 20 20 20 | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -V | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`

It will print the number you want.